# Why startup doesn't want to start?

Tags: intellij-idea, xampp

I have a project `"GPSMonitoringSystem"` in `IntelliJ`. I run it, but when I want to see if it works I go in directory `bin` of Tomcat and I make double click on `startup.bat`. On that moment a `command prompt` start, but after a second close instantly. Why and how I can fix it ?

Comment: Can't you set a break somewhere?

Comment: I want to start startup just to see if server works